# Как получить количество репостов на Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook-api

Метод sharedposts возвращает репосты конкретной записи, это то, что мне нужно, но если запись создана не пользователем (приложением), то sharedposts возвращает пустой ответ. Насколько я понимаю, эти записи (посты) отличаются только полем `status_type`. Через FQL эти поля не доступны, а через api не меняются. Есть ли способ посчитать репосты записей, созданных приложением?